# javascript - can't correctly dynamically load scripts and styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anybody can help me with one problem?

I'm making some javascript. In this script I need to load dynamically some other scripts and styles. Logic of my script demands, that all of this scripts and styles have to be loaded in some order and only when all of them are loaded - after that some script code executes.

Problem is that I can't achieve that all scripts and styles dynamically loads in correct order. Not every time, but sometimes I can see that some script or style doesn't load yet but next script already trying to load.

I explored this ussue and got some usefull methods. For example, setting "async" to "false".
But I still can't solve this problem somehow.

Here's the part of js where I'm trying to load scripts and styles dynamically.

```
function loadScripts() {
  var fileref;

  fileref=document.createElement('script');
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  fileref.setAttribute("src", "script1.js");
  fileref.async = false;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);

  fileref=document.createElement("link");
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  fileref.setAttribute("href", "style1.css");
  fileref.async = false;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);

  fileref=document.createElement("link");
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  fileref.setAttribute("href", "style2.css");
  fileref.async = false;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);

  fileref=document.createElement('script');
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  fileref.setAttribute("src", "script2.js");
  fileref.async = false;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
```

In this example "script1.js" and "style1.css" are much larger than other scripts and styles. Sometimes "style1.css" starts to load although "script1.js" isn't loaded yet. It causes exceptions and other problems.

Please take a look and tell me what is wrong with this code? And what would be correct?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You are not actually loading the scripts here, you are just adding their reference to the DOM, so the order in which they complete is not one-directional like JavaScript is. Once its inserted, javascript is done and the browser loads the elements at the same time, so that might explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jQuery:

```
//Add Css File
$("head").append($('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').attr('href', 'my.css'));
```

Works for me:)

For more complex loading I would suggest [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)